# Not able to locate Element with same id

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I havw two element with same attribute inside iframe , ..

problem is that driver can click on first element but not able to click on second element.

Here is HTML for that :

first one :

```
<div class="textalgncent mergeSteps mgrT12">

                    <a onclick="javascript:return LoadNextStep('2','1');" id="lnkNextStep" title="Next Step" class="BlueBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkNextStep','')">NEXT STEP</a>
                    <a onclick="javascript:return Refresh(1);" id="lnkRefresh" title="Refresh" class="BlueBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkRefresh','')" style="display: none;">REFRESH</a>
                    <a onclick="javascript:return CancelMergeContact();" id="lnkCancel" title="Cancel" class="DisableBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkCancel','')">CANCEL</a>


                </div>
```

Second One :

```
<div class="textalgncent mergeSteps mgrT12">

                    <a onclick="javascript:return LoadNextStep('3','2');" id="lnkNextStep" title="Next Step" class="BlueBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkNextStep','')">NEXT STEP</a>
                    <a onclick="javascript:return Refresh(2);" id="lnkRefresh" title="Refresh" class="BlueBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkRefresh','')" style="display: inline-block;">REFRESH</a>
                    <a onclick="javascript:return CancelMergeContact();" id="lnkCancel" title="Cancel" class="DisableBtn mgrRL10" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkCancel','')">CANCEL</a>

                    <a onclick="javascript:return LoadNextStep('1','2');" id="lnkBack" title="Back" class="BlueBtn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkBack','')">BACK</a>
                </div>
```

How do make my driver to click on second one , has they are in same frame and has same attribute.

Code I have tried :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("fbContent");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlDominantId']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlDominantId']/option[2]")).click();
waitele();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkNextStep']")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='lnkNextStep']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkNextStep']")).click()
```

Comment: have to tried wait over there? Are you trying to click on Back now ? what was your 1st element

Comment: show code and exception if you are facing

Comment: Its say unable to locate element :driver.switchTo().frame("fbContent");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlDominantId']")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlDominantId']/option[2]")).click();
  waitele();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkNextStep']")).click();
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@onclick='lnkNextStep']")));

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lnkNextStep']")).click();

Comment: update question with this code, not provide it as a comment- it's totally not readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please do it like below

**Note** talking under consideration that you are inside the i frame `driver.switchTo().frame("fbContent");`

now its very simple to work with two elements with same attribute please do it like below take the common attributes inside the list

```
 List<WebElement> commonElements = driver.findElements(By.id("lnkNextStep"));
      //Now only for verification purpose check the size 
      // otherwise not required

  System.out.println("Size of the common elements in the ifrmae is : "+commonElements.size());

  // now its very simple two click the second element with same attribute
  commonElements.get(1).click();  // as index of 2nd element will be 1.
```

Hope this solves your query

Comment: No It does not work for me , Size of ELement come out to be 1 in this case .

Comment: i have re-verified at my end and its working as expected,can you provide me the actual web page so that i can have a look at that

Comment: Its working , i need to again switch to same iframe , then it is able to locate  web element , No why I need to do that .

Comment: if in  case its not working then only otherwise not needed ,i am happy that it worked for you